# Meteor ORM Polymorphic & Mongo Documents

Tags: meteor

I hear there's a [forthcoming Meteor ORM](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/aawhBBHsDrk).

I'm interested in working with it in a similar way to [Polymorphic Models for Django](https://github.com/bconstantin/django_polymorphic).

Firstly, is polymorphic representation similar to django-polymorphic available with Mongo Documents, and secondly, how might it be done with Meteor Collections?

Comment: https://github.com/emmerge/graviton

Answer (score 0):

At the time you wrote your question, this was probably not doable but now it is achievable by using the `transform` option on either the instantiation of `new Mongo.Collection` or when doing `MyCollection.find` or `findOne`. Given that you want to do polymorphic models, you would most likely use the `transform` option during querying.

Check out the `transform` option in the following documentation:

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone

Here is an example:

```
// Your MongoDB collections
Resources = new Mongo.Collection('resource');

// Define your model
function ProductModel (resource) { /* Model Stuff */ }

// As you fetch your data, instantiate the models using the `transform` option
var product = Resources.findOne(myFilter, {
  transform: function (document) {
    return new ProductModel(document);
  }
});
```

There are a bunch of packages out there that give you the ability of models right off the bat like [Astronomy](https://atmospherejs.com/jagi/astronomy) and [Graviton](https://github.com/emmerge/graviton).